# Why do the Repositories not have the latest upstream versions?

Tags: official-repositories

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

As a new Ubuntu user, I'm still trying to figure out the software management system. I've noticed a few times already (most recently today, looking for Emacs 24.1) that the packages available in the repositories are lagging behind, sometimes seriously behind, current stable releases. Then I end up installing from the binaries, but I think that means I'm giving up the ability to follow updates further down the line.

I'm guess I'm just wondering how the apt repositories get updated, and by whom. When there's a lag, is it because the developer hasn't pushed the most recent release onto the relevant server? Is there a lot more work for the developer in getting the release into a form the repository can use?

I expect there's an article out there somewhere explaining all this, but I haven't been able to find it.