# Why apt-get doesn't install the newest software

Tags: software-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do the Repositories not have the latest upstream versions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150445/why-do-the-repositories-not-have-the-latest-upstream-versions)

I tried installing some software using apt-get or default software manager. Unfortunately, it didn't install the newest available software, e.g. conky installed version is 1.8.1, while the newest is 1.9, NetBeans is 7.0.1 instead of 7.1.2. What should I add or what should I change to install the newest software?

Answer (score 0):

You should take notice that with apt-get you are installing the newest software in the Ubuntu Repositories, not the newest version of the software, if you want the latest you'll need to go to the developers page and download it