# Updates in libreoffice in main repository

Tags: updates, libreoffice, repository

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do the Repositories not have the latest upstream versions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150445/why-do-the-repositories-not-have-the-latest-upstream-versions)
>   [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Why does LO in the main repository don't keep up with the latest libreoffice version? 3.5.4 offers for example huge improvements in speed. Unless the packages gets updated in the main repository most users wont see the new build.

I know there is a PPA, but sometimes it breaks things (for example the 3.5.5 rc2 amd64 build is stuck (since yesterday!!) in building because of low storage space https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ppa/+build/3609969 )